# Extract substring from a line in python, if another keyword is found

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to work with regex in python to extract a small substring from a large string, if another keyword is found in the string.

e.g. -

```
s = "1  0001    1   UG  science,ee;YEAR=onefour;standard->2;district->9"

if "year" in s:
    print ("The year is = ",VALUE_OF_YEAR)<--- here I hope to somehow get the year substring from the above string and print it.
```

i.e. the answer will look like

```
The year is = onefour
```

Please note - the value will change if its denoting a different number like onethree, oneseven, etc

I basically want to copy whatever starts from after

```
=
```

till the

```
;
```

if I find

```
YEAR
```

in the string and print it out

I am not too sure how to do this.

I tried using string manipulation methods in python, but so far I haven't found any way to precisely copy off all the words till the ';' in the string.

Any help will be appreciated. Any other method is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to grab that value:

```
(?<=\bYEAR=)[^;]+
```

The regex matches:

- `(?<=\bYEAR=)`  If the string we are looking for is preceded with a whole word `YEAR=`...
- `[^;]+` - match 1 or more characters other than `;`.

Here is [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wP0lK9/1)

Here is [sample Python code](http://ideone.com/ZXqBjR):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=\bYEAR=)[^;]+')
test_str = "1  0001    1   UG  science,ee;YEAR=onefour;standard->2;district->9"
robj = re.search(p, test_str)
if robj:
    print(robj.group(0))
```

If everyone is so fond of capturing groups, here is the same expression with the lookbehind replaced with a capturing group:

```
\bYEAR=([^;]+)
```

And in Python:

```
p = re.compile(r'\bYEAR=([^;]+)')
test_str = "1  0001    1   UG  science,ee;YEAR=onefour;standard->2;district->9"
robj = re.search(p, test_str)
if robj:
    print(robj.group(1))
```

Note that in case your `YEAR` value has hyphens or other non-word characters in it, `\w` will not help you. The negated character class is your best friend here.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help with this.

Comment: I actually found this easier to understand and implement !

Answer (score 4):

You can also have a [*saving group*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) capture the `year` value:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"YEAR=(\w+);")
>>> s = "1  0001    1   UG  science,ee;YEAR=onefour;standard->2;district->9"
>>> pattern.search(s).group(1)
'onefour'
```

You may also need to handle cases when there is no match. For example, return `None`:

```
import re

def get_year_value(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r"YEAR=(\w+);")
    match = pattern.search(s)

    return match.group(1) if match else None
```

Comment: This seems the easiest to understand `+1`

Comment: Easiest to understand does not mean the safest.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use,

```
if "YEAR" in s:
    year= s.split('YEAR=')[1].split(';')[0]
    print ("The year is = " +year)
#this is the output
> The year is = onefour
```

Basically what it is doing is splitting the line after `YEAR=` and before `;`.  The `[1]` splits the right of the sub string `YEAR=` and the `[0]` splits the left of the sub string `;`

Answer (score 0):

```
YEAR=(?P<year>\w+);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
".*(?=YEAR).*YEAR=(.*?);.*"g
```

with substitution `/1`

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/rR3gH5/1)